# How to convert Christian year to Thai year in Java?

Tags: java, android

Now I get value of date time from JSON like this `"end_datetime": "2020-12-31 20:08:00"`

but I want to convert year from 2020 > 2563 when I get value in `Textview`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`ThaiBuddhistDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ThaiBuddhistDate.html) class in package -  `java.time.chrono`

you can use below example for reference -

```
    public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String date = "2020-12-31 20:08:00";
        // Convert Thai Buddhist date to ISO date

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
        try {
            ThaiBuddhistDate thaiBuddhistNow = ThaiBuddhistDate.from(LocalDate.parse(date,formatter));
            System.out.println("Thai  Buddhist Current Date  from  ISO:  "
                    + thaiBuddhistNow);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```